# DataGrid doesnt show all properties of an object which implement interface

Tags: c#

I have an interface defined as below.

```
public interface IDraw
{
    int DrawID {get;set;},
    int Num1 {get;set;}
}
```

and I have 2 classes which implement the interface

```
public class DrawOne:IDraw
{
    public int DrawID {get; set;}
    public int Num1 { get; set;}
    public int Num2 { get ; set;}
}

public class DrawOne : IDraw
{
    public int DrawID {get; set;}
    public int Num1 { get; set;}
    public int Num2 { get ; set;} 
    public int Num3 { get; set;}
}
```

And I have another interface which defines a method as below

```
 public interface IDrawType
 {
     IDraw GetData();
 }
```

there is another class which implements this interface.

```
public class MyDrawTypeOne : IDrawType
{
     public IDraw GetData()
     {
        DrawOne drawOne =  new DrawOne();
        drawOne.DrawID = 1001;
        drawOne.Num1 = 8;
        drawOne.Num2 = 9;

        return drawOne;
      }
}
```

I am implementing the above objects' definition as below

```
public class ImplementationClass
{
     public void ButtonClick()
     {
         List<IDraw> listData = new List<IDraw>();
         MyDrawTypeOne drawOne =  new MyDrawTypeOne();
          for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                IDraw data = drawOne.GetDrawData();
                listData.Add(data);
            }
           gridDraw.DataSource = listData;
     } 
}
```

The problem I have here is , the data grid only display DrawID and Num1. I am not able to see the Num2 in the data grid. Is there anything I am missing here?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What UI library are you using? WPF, WinForms or ASP.NET?

Comment: It is because `IDraw` doesn't have `Num2`

Comment: I understand that it doesn't have num2. However, I would like to to understand if there is any way that I could use to display the Num2. The idea is, I am using dependency injection to resolve the object IDrawType, which will assign the data to the grid.. For example. If the object resolved is MyDrawTypeOne then the grid should display Num1 and Num2 , If the object resolved is MyDrawTypeTwo then then grid should display NUm1, NUm2 and Num3.

Comment: @Alan What would happen then if your list ends up with both `MyDrawTypeOne` AND `MyDrawTypeTwo`?

Answer (score 3):

You're binding to a list of type `IDraw`, so your DataGrid is showing all the public properties on that interface. If you want it to show additional properties, you would need to either add them to your `IDraw` interface or change the list you're binding against to `List<DrawOne>`.

Comment: I am afraid, I would only be able to know if the object resolved using dependency injection is DrawOne or DrawTwo during runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Your Interface IDraw only has DrawID and Num1 as properties. No Num2.